# Correct word to use: from or with

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Which word is correct in these two sentences?

1. A child may also suffer from/with a runny nose.
2. A child may also suffer from/with a fever.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suffer), there's the option 'suffer from'

Google books source shows a [descending graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffer%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuffer%20with%3B%2Cc0) for 'suffer with'

1) suffer + object (*he suffered intense pain*)

2) suffer + no object (*he'd suffered a great deal since his arrest*)

3) **suffer from (*his daughter suffered from agoraphobia***)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is from, they suffer from [what they suffer from]. If you say that they suffer with, it will be understood, however quite awkward.